# Single log file

Tags: serilog

I would like to have a single log file that will be rolled on the size limit, previous file will be removed so there is only one log file at a time. Exaxmple:

`logs.txt` raches 10MB --> delete `logs.txt` start writing to `logs_001.txt`

My current code is:

```
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .WriteTo.File(
                    LogFile,
                    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                    retainedFileCountLimit: 1,
                    fileSizeLimitBytes: 10485760) //10MB
                .CreateLogger();
```

The code is from a Xamarin Forms project and it's executed every time the application is initialized.

The issue with that code is that on each application initialization a new log file is created, the previous one is deleted but the file size limit is not respected. So if the log file size is
lower than 10MB it will still roll to a new file at each start of the application.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to simply remove `rollOnFileSizeLimit: true`